# Graphviz: forbid horizontal edges, always show vertical orientation

Tags: graphviz, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a directed acyclic graph that I am trying to visualize using Graphviz's `dot`.  By default it's laid out top-to-bottom.

Usually, all directed edges have their head lower than their tail.  But in certain cases they're drawn as a horizontal straight line section, i.e. head and tail are at the same level.  In my case this happened after I defined subgraph clusters.

Is their a way to forbid this and force it to *always* position nodes so that the arrows are pointing "downwards"?

[image]

Sample source:

```
digraph {
  rankdir=TB;
  subgraph cluster_1 { "8"; "7"; "9"; "11"; "10" }
  subgraph cluster_2 { "3"; "4"; "5"; }

  "1" -> "3";
  "2" -> "5";
  "3" -> "6";
  "3" -> "5";
  "2" -> "8";
  "2" -> "4";
  "2" -> "3";
  "2" -> "6";
  "2" -> "7";
  "1" -> "8";
  "7" -> "8";
  "4" -> "6";
  "6" -> "10";
  "3" -> "11";
  "7" -> "10";
  "7" -> "6";
  "1" -> "2";
  "6" -> "5";
  "7" -> "9";
  "7" -> "5";
  "4" -> "5";
  "6" -> "8";
  "3" -> "4";
  "10" -> "11";
  "4" -> "11";
  "3" -> "8";
  "8" -> "9";
  "6" -> "9";
  "9" -> "10";
  "3" -> "10";
  "3" -> "7";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I will provide this answer for future reference:

You could use `newrank = true;` which does the following according to the [graphviz.org website](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:newrank):

> The original ranking algorithm in dot is recursive on clusters. This can produce fewer ranks and a more compact layout, but sometimes at the cost of a head node being place on a higher rank than the tail node. It also assumes that a node is not constrained in separate, incompatible subgraphs. For example, a node cannot be in a cluster and also be constrained by rank=same with a node not in the cluster.
>
> If newrank=true, the ranking algorithm does a single global ranking, ignoring clusters. This allows nodes to be subject to multiple constraints. Rank constraints will usually take precedence over edge constraints.

So your source only changes as follows:

```
  digraph {
      rankdir=TB;
      newrank = true;
      ...
```

And the result will be much nicer for this example:

[image]

Comment: Don't assume that answers to old questions won't be appreciated!  The ideal StackOverflow question/answer will be useful for many future readers, even years later.

Comment: Thanks for adding the image. It's interesting that the default ranking algorithm orders the clusters from right-to-left, while the newer algorithm orders these from left-to-right

Answer (score 1):

That behaviour is caused by the clusters which fix the node rank inside. 'Force' from outside edges does pull nodes horizontally but has no influence on the rank.

You have to either avoid clusters or insert invisible nodes and edges.

A minimal example showing the rank fix

```
digraph {
    subgraph cluster_1 {
        1
        3
    }
    1 -> 2
    2 -> 3
}
```

[image]